# DiscordJS: Why is the bot sending more messages as I run the command multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The code below is wrapped in a class that gets called when specific commands is ran, for example `!dm`. When I run !dm after starting the bot, it normally sends a message and waits for the user to reply back to the sent message(code below). When I run !dm the second time, it sends a message two times. If I run !dm once more, it sends the message 3 times and so on... Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```js
this.client.on("messageCreate", function (msg) {
            if (msg.author.bot || msg.channel.type !== "DM") return
            console.log("something")
})
```

*(This is the shortened code)*

Full code: [PasteHub](https://pastehub.net/b476024e7ee)

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be the default behaviour, because the bot will always be listening to the `messageCreate` event. I think you would need some kind of state for the bot, for eg:

If `user1` typed `!DM`, you would store that info somewhere, like:

```js
const botStates = [];

// Message event closure {
botStates.push({
    user: user.name, // example
    bot_state: 'waiting',
})
// }
```

And then you could check that state each time the event triggers the closure, and if the state for that user is `waiting`, you would not send the message.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to you storing two client events inside of the each other.

Make sure that you are not storing your `messageCreate` inside of another event.